# calling childview from fragment onclick listener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

Am developing an app where i need to call multiple `ListFragments` on same activity. It contains main parent `ListFragment` with 10 rows in it.
By clicking each row i need to open new child `ListView` next to parent `ListView` as like this[image: ()]. And my coding is

```
public class FragmentListArray extends Activity {


     static String[] TITLES = 
            {
                    "Henry IV (1)",   
                    "Henry V",
                    "Henry VIII",       
                    "Richard II",
                    "Richard III",
                    "Merchant of Venice",  
                    "Othello",
                    "King Lear"
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            ArrayListFragment list = new ArrayListFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FragmentListArray.TITLES));
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          // here i need to achieve my childview click listener..
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to set onitem click listener. Help me in achieving the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use drop down menu which you can setup for showing the second menu. If you want you can check this link : http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/show-listview-as-drop-down-android.html

Comment: @ArshadParwez thanks for ur reply. I want to use listfragment and by clicking that i need my child listview to be appear.

Comment: You can pass a custom listview in the dropdown menu. It would appear as a sublist

Comment: @ArshadParwez My parent listview needs to be static and by clicking i need to hide/show my childviews. By using dropdown menu my parentview won't be stable..

Comment: No. Your parent view will also be visible & the drop down will appear just below the list item you have tapped on.

Comment: @ArshadParwez Can i achieve the same using fragment cause i need that only in fragment. and can u give me an example for the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39732/discussion-between-arshad-parwez-and-all-is-well)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActivity()` and cast the result to your activity's class to get instance of the Activity, which holds the fragment.
Define some function that will accept the id of the item, depending on which you need to load data in the sectond list Fragment. Should look like this:

```
YourActivity activity = (YourActivity)getActivity();
activity.fillSecondFragment(clickedItemId);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to achieve it's very similiar to android developers example about fragments, instead a normal fragment when list item click use your listfragmnet (which in fact is a fragment)

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html